# How to create an in place method to transpose a matrix only using pointers?

Tags: c, transpose

I'm trying to create a function, in C, that only uses pointers and transposes a matrix in place. I'm not able to accomplish it. This is the code I have so far:

```
    void transpose(int matrix[ROWS][COLS]) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         for (int j=0;j<5;j++) {
              int temp = *(*(matrix + i) + j);
              *(*(matrix + i) + j) =  *(*(matrix + j) + i);
              *(*(matrix + j) + i) = temp;
           }
        }
      }
```

Comment: It would be much more readable if you used the array indexing notation. This won't break your "pointers only" requirement.

Comment: Are you only concerned with a 5x5 matrix? Why not pass the size of the matrix in as additional parameters?

Comment: In general, transposing matrices in place is not simple. If the matrix is square, you just need to swap elements. But you would not swap all elements with their partners—because if you swap `a` with `b` and also `b` with `a`, then you just undo the swap. You only want to swap half the elements with their partners, like those above the diagonal with those below the diagonal. For non-square matrices, transposing in place induces irregular permutations that are a nuisance to plan and execute. Are you sure this is the problem you were given?

Comment: Do not declare a matrix using `ROWS` and `COLS` and then use `5` and `5` in the loop bounds. Use `ROWS` and `COLS` for the loop bounds. Or, if `ROWS` and `COLS` are the storage capacity but the actual matrix to be transposed may be smaller, use some named thing for the loop bounds to make it clear—do not use arbitrary numerals like `5` in source code without explaining them.

Answer (score 0):

You are swapping every thing twice. The second loop should be for j < i.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         for (int j=0;j<i;j++) {
              int temp = *(*(matrix + i) + j);
              *(*(matrix + i) + j) =  *(*(matrix + j) + i);
              *(*(matrix + j) + i) = temp;
           }
        }
```